# git-ftp fatal: Remote host not set

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci, git-ftp

I'm getting this error after pipeline runs:

```
Preparing to unpack .../git-ftp_1.3.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-ftp (1.3.1-1) ...
Setting up libcurl3:amd64 (7.52.1-5+deb9u6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Setting up curl (7.52.1-5+deb9u6) ...
Setting up git-ftp (1.3.1-1) ...
$ git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD sftp://$FTP_HOST
fatal: Remote host not set.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This is my .yml config:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

stage_deploy:
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
    - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD sftp://$FTP_HOST
```

A month ago it worked fine. The values of the variables are correct..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it pressing the "Clear Runner Caches" button and running it again.

Answer (score 1):

Before you make `git ftp push` you have to initialize `git ftp`, so add the line:

`- git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST`

> note: this only work for the first time

or if you want to execute this every commit add the line before  `git ftp push` :

`- git reset --hard`

Comment: The OP has solved this issue and OP told how he did it.